# What are the %functions in JavaScript source code?

Tags: javascript, v8

Looking through the promise code in v8 source code, I noticed a lot of functions that starts with %, what are those? do they have any special meaning?

example here https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/3.29.45/src/promise.js?autodive=0%2F
like `%DebugPushPromise`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're internal built-in *runtime functions*. More info here: https://v8.dev/docs/builtin-functions